# lgith sensor arduino + max + instrument 

Tags: max-msp

Hi, I'm a complete novice at aurdino and max, and hope to make a device as follow;

setting : three light sensors are connected to arduino, arduino is connected to max.

purpose : three light sensors' serial values control the pitch, tempo, amd volume of a wav file in max.

How can I make it possible ?  (Hardware setting on aurdino and bread board, code for aurnoino software, and code for max ?)

Answer (score 1):

If you've not used the Arduino before I suggest looking at [Maxuino](http://www.maxuino.org/about) as this will take care of the processing code to control the arduino (giving you one less thing to learn). It's still a fairly steep learning curve just for Max, so give yourself plenty of time. Find LDRs ([light dependent resistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor)) tested by the arduino community so you're sure they are going to work with little fuss.  The [Max forums](http://www.cycling74.com/forums/) are pretty good, so have a go and then ask (Max) questions there.

Sounds like a fun project.. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ask here:
http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?action=forum

Also:
http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/MaxMSP

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out Peter Elsea's tutorial on Max, Arduino & Firmata.

ftp://arts.ucsc.edu/pub/ems/MaxTutors/advancedMax/Notes%20on%20Firmata.pdf